# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run the following code:

**test/models/tweet_test.rb**

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TweetTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "Tweet should not be null" do
    tweet = true
    assert tweet
  end
end
```

I receive this error:

```
tweet_test.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport (NameError)
```

I am following along with a tutorial perfectly. Why is this happening? Has ActiveSuport::TestCase been deprecated?

UPDATE:
I attempted to `require 'test_helper'` :

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'test_helper'

class TweetTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "Tweet should not be null" do
    tweet = true
    assert tweet
  end
end
```

But received the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)
```

Comment: What if you *only* require `test_helper`? And is your testfile inside the folder `/test`?

Comment: Same thing. And yeah, this is inside test/models/tweet_test.rb

Comment: Is the file `/test/test_helper.rb` present and does it contain something that looks like it was never messed with after you ran `rails new my_project`? If not, create a new empty Rails project and copy the freshly generated  `test_helper` file into your current project.

Comment: The file is present and it is the default Rails installs with

Answer (score 2):

You are not requiring the correct Rails minitest files to setup an `ActiveSupport::TestCase`. That is a Rails specific class that cannot be found in minitest alone. Are you sure you are working inside a Rails project?

In most cases, you setup a test in Rails by requiring `test_helper` in your test class so you can inherit from `ActiveSupport::TestCase`. The file `test_helper` contains all the requirements and setup for running tests in a Rails project.

**Quick fix**: just inherit from `Minitest::Test`.

Comment: Yeah, I am running this from within Rails. I am trying to test one of my models. requiring test_helper does not work either. I'll post the results of that above